# Find Unconnected Subregions

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, computational-geometry

If I have a region, how can I identify sub regions that may be disconnected, if any exist?

`region` defines a rectangular region given  two diagonally opposed vertices.

```
region[{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}}]:=Module[{sort1=Sort[{x1,x2}],sort2=Sort[{y1,y2}]},
ImplicitRegion[(sort1[[1]]<= x <= sort1[[2]])\[And](sort2[[1]]<= y <= sort2[[2]]),{x,y}]]
```

Here we define two rectangular regions, `r1` and `r2` that intersect.

```
r1 = region[{{4, -3}, {-7, 6}}];
r2 = region[{{4, -7}, {0, 7}}];
RegionPlot[{r1, r2}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, BaseStyle -> 16, PlotLegends -> {r1, r2}]
```

[image: two regions]

---

In the present case, one of  region differences, `r3` consists of a single region.

```
r3 = RegionDifference[r1, r2];
RegionPlot[{r3}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotLegends -> {r3}, BaseStyle -> 16]
```

[image: r3]

---

The other, `r4`, turns out to have two subregions.

```
r4 = RegionDifference[r2, r1];
RegionPlot[{r4}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotLegends -> {r4}, BaseStyle -> 16]
```

[image: r4]

I would like to programmatically determine how many unconnected subregions a region has and also obtain algebraic descriptions of each.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to programmatically determine how many unconnected subregions a region has

```
ConnectedMeshComponents@DiscretizeRegion@r4
```

[image]

> and also obtain algebraic descriptions of each.

Sorry.

Comment: First time I see `ConnectedMeshComponents` put to use. Nice.

Comment: @David: I just typed `Connected` into a notebook hoping something related to connected components would show up, and there it was.

Answer (score 3):

### An Algebraic Route

`Reduce` enables us to answer the second question (How do I obtain algebraic descriptions of each unconnected subregion?) without even creating Regions.

```
equation[{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}}]:=Module[{sort1=Sort[{x1,x2}],sort2=Sort[{y1,y2}]},(sort1[[1]]<= x <= sort1[[2]])\[And](sort2[[1]]<= y <= sort2[[2]])]
```

This is very much like the `region` function but it returns an equation instead of a region.

```
eq1 = equation[{{4, -3}, {-7, 6}}]
eq2 = equation[{{4, -7}, {0, 7}}]
Reduce[eq2 && ! eq1, {x, y}]
```

> -7 <= x <= 4 && -3 <= y <= 6
>
> 0 <= x <= 4 && -7 <= y <= 7
>
> 0 <= x <= 4 && (-7 <= y < -3 || 6 < y <= 7)

I would still need to break up the bottom equation into two separate equations.

---

**Update**:

Then, using **kguler's suggestion** (in comments, below)

```
BooleanConvert[Reduce[eq2 && ! eq1, {x, y}]] /. Or -> List
```

one obtains

> {-7 <= y < -3 && 0 <= x <= 4, 0 <= x <= 4 && 6 < y <= 7}

---

### Using `MeshRegion`

**Rahul** notes (in another answer) that `ConnectedMeshComponents` can be used to return the subregions as separate regions.  Because the regions are polygonal (specifically, rectangular) we may then obtain the bounds of each subregion using `RegionBounds`.

[image: region bounds]

> {{{0., 4.}, {-7., -3.}}, {{0., 4.}, {6., 7.}}}

Using

```
equation/@%
```

we get

> {-7. <= x <= 0. && -3. <= y <= 4., 0. <= x <= 6. && 4. <= y <= 7.}

`RegionBounds` turns out to be very useful.
Nonetheless, note that the bounds returned are non-integers.

The algebraic route, described above, returns integer bounds.

Comment: maybe `BooleanConvert[Reduce[eq2 && ! eq1, {x, y}]] /. Or -> List`? (+1)

Comment: kguler, Yes, exactly!  Very good.

Answer (score 2):

Use Image processing functions:

```
MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[Image[RegionPlot[{r3}, Frame -> None]]]] // Max
```

1

```
MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[Image[RegionPlot[{r4}, Frame -> None]]]] // Max
```

2

As for the second question:  if you need the region bounds, use the previous solution and then:

```
RegionBounds /@ (ConnectedMeshComponents@DiscretizeRegion@r4)
```

Comment: That answers the first question.